# Sorting columns within a filter/query tab

Tags: sorting, filter, google-sheets

I have this very specific formula I've written in Google sheets to pull in all of the data from another tab, matching criteria where the `date = "this week."` This is the formula:

```
=FILTER(QUERY('Confirmed Shoots'!A1:Y,"Select J,K,G,H,I,C,E,F,M,L,D,N,P"), WEEKNUM('Confirmed Shoots'!G1:G)=WEEKNUM(NOW()))
```

I want to make sure that everything is sorted by row G, and then row H (both ascending). I tried this:

```
=FILTER(QUERY('Confirmed Shoots'!A1:Y,"Select J,K,G,H,I,C,E,F,M,L,D,N,P"), WEEKNUM('Confirmed Shoots'!G1:G)=WEEKNUM(NOW())) order by G, H asc ")
```

But that gave me an error. I also tried a `=sort` function, but that also gave me an error, and I wasn't sure about the appropriate syntax for that. Can you tell me where I should put the "order by G, H" or how to incorporate a `=sort` without messing up the equation?